# How to extract only desired text between characters within a cell containing repeating patterns in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office, text-extraction

### The Problem:

I have a list of lead data that contains the first and last names of my leads in the same cell. This data and other data that I do not need to extract are found between double quotation marks.

**Example of the Data**

The cell data containing the first and last names appears like this:

a:6:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:10:"First Name";s:5:"value";s:7:"LEAD FIRST NAME";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Last Name";s:5:"value";s:7:"LEAD LAST NAME";}i:2;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Email";s:5:"value";s:21:"ALREADY HAVE THIS";}i:3;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:12:"Phone Number";s:5:"value";s:10:"9095551234";}i:4;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:21:"Comments or Questions";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}i:5;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:17:"Google Mandatory ";s:5:"value";s:0:"";}}

The **LEAD FIRST NAME** *is always between the seventh and eighth quotation marks*, and the **LEAD LAST NAME** *is always between the fifteenth and sixteenth quotation marks*. Of course, the **length of the first and last name values are different for each row (lead)**, ruling out using the mid or len options.

I have searched for quite some time, trying to come up with a solution. Unfortunately, nothing I have tried has given me anything close to the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the data like this:

```
    Dim InputData As String
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim LastName As String

    InputData = Range("A1").Value
    FirstName = Split(InputData, Chr(34))(7)
    LastName = Split(InputData, Chr(34))(15)

    MsgBox(FirstName)
    MsgBox(LastName)
```

If you changed:

```
FirstName = Split(InputData, Chr(34))(7)
```

to:

```
FirstName = Split(InputData, Chr(34))(0)
```

The output would be: a:6:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the first name and last name are different lengths so for one lead the first name might be 7 characters and for the next it could be 4. Same for the last name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `FILTERXML` function (Windows Excel 2013+) you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[position()=8 or position()=16]")
```

This will return a 2 node array of the FIRST and LAST names which, unfortunately, in Excel 2016, won't SPILL into the two cells as it would with Office 365.

So you could array enter (with `ctrl+shift+enter`) the formula over two cells, or split it into two formulas for the first and last names separately.

```
FIRST NAME: =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[8]")
LAST NAME:  =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[16]")
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I am out of luck with this particular solution as I use a Macintosh. But, thank you very much for your time and information.